# Revoking Distribution certificate for iPhone

Tags: iphone, certificate, distribution

If I revoke the distribution certificate for a iPhone app that is already in the App store, will it stop working for customers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't revoque an AppStore certificate.
I think you are confusing with the adHoc certificate.

Comment: Just confirming that Appstore certificate will not be affected. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can revoke your main development and distribution certificates (there is REVOKE button beside them), which is different from the provisioning profiles (which can also be revoked).